# How to improve face detection performance with OpenCV on Android?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, qt-creator

I'm working on an Android project where I'm using OpenCV to detect faces through the camera. The application detects faces correctly, but the performance is very slow. I have checked multiple times for this problem, but I didn't find any solution. Is there any way to improve the performance?

My code is:

```
      QVideoFrame FilterRunnable::run( QVideoFrame *input,
                             const QVideoSurfaceFormat &surfaceFormat,
                             QVideoFilterRunnable::RunFlags flags )
      {
          input->map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);
          QImage image = imageWrapper(*input);
          image = image.scaled(640,480);
          cv::Mat mat(image.width(),image.height(),CV_8UC3,image.bits(),                image.bytesPerLine());

          vector< Rect > detectedFaces;
          detectedFaces.clear();
          frontalFaceClassifier.detectMultiScale( mat, detectedFaces,
                                   1.6, 3, 2 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE ,  Size(60,60) );

          qDebug()<<"Cantidad de caras en el vector : " << detectedFaces.size();
          if( detectedFaces.size() > 0 ){
              actualFace = detectedFaces.at( 0 );

          countDetectedFaces++;
          qDebug()<<"**********qwerty**********"<<detectedFaces.size();
          }
          for(int i=0;i<detectedFaces.size();i++)
          {
            Rect dibujarCuadrado = detectedFaces.at(i);

            cv::rectangle (mat, dibujarCuadrado, 20, 1, LINE_8, 0);
          }
      }
```

Comment: What if you moved the heavy lifting off the mobile, and do that part in the  cloud.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. I think it would be a very good idea although it would depend a lot on having a good internet I think. Do you have some porject where it eliminates some processing part to the cloud to guide me? If so it would be of great help, thank you very much.

Comment: @Wayne Keep in mind that would mean pushing about a megabyte per image to the server. I'm in a city and my LTE upstream is barely 2 Mbps (And I bet there are many people much worse off)

Comment: LBP cascade should be somewhat faster than Haar but with the same accuracy

Comment: Hi Andrey , thanks for answering, I have a question When you say you use LBP cascade, do you know if it is enough to use the xml of lbp cascade instead of the cascade haar? or do I have to change many things in the code? Try to use the LBP xml in my project and although it walks a little faster, I think it could also be better. If you have any idea, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you have implemented one haar classifier only. I assumed you use the frontleface one. You may incorporate the profile face classifier(available in opencv haar package) in an else statement to increase accuracy. In general, you can train any classifier u want and incorporate them. For training a classifier, this is an awesome video [here](https://youtu.be/eay7CgPlCyo)

Comment: Thank you very much, the idea would be to implement also what you say, but first increasing the speed of the camera. Because if I go slow with only one classifier, with two I think it would be worse.

Comment: I did a similar task with python before, face detection with haar cascade has little latency because it just processes the frame into the xml. Did u turn yr frame into gray?

Comment: I turn the frame in gray in my project and the performance got better and without lose accuracy in the face detection, thanks for your advice